# How can I vertically centralize a Bootstrap V4 modal with CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How can I centralize a [Bootstrap V4 modal](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) with CSS?

Comment: could you wrap it in the vertical-align utility class? http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/

Comment: I tried align-middle, but did not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can vertical center the modal by overriding the position of the `.modal-dialog` like this..

```
.modal.show .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/14Ki1kyTgo

**Update 2018**

As of Bootstrap 4 Beta 3, there is a new `modal-dialog-centered` class that can be used instead of the custom method described above.

https://www.codeply.com/go/lpOtIFoN6E (Beta 3)

Comment: That is surely working. Can I ask why *translate(0,-50%);* is also needed?

Comment: It's a vertical centering [trick](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/). It finds the center of the viewport (`top: 50%` & `transform: translateY(-50%)`) when the height of the element (modal) is unknown.

Comment: @wonderfulworld, note using this centering method on modals taller than the viewport causes the top part of the modal to become inaccessible.

Comment: I don't know why but this fix doesn't work at chrome on Iphone 6+

Answer (score 3):

Using Flexbox its really easy to add vertical align bootstrap 4 modal popup. Here's the CSS Code.

[**See Woking Demo**](https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/dzOWQw)

**SASS**

```
.modal-open .modal.modal-center {
    display: flex!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    .modal-dialog {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
}
```

**Compiled CSS**

```
.modal-open .modal.modal-center {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  -webkit-box-align: center !important;
      -ms-flex-align: center !important;
          align-items: center !important;
}
.modal-open .modal.modal-center .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[**See Woking Demo**](https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/dzOWQw)